# Raphael: Remove a Set

Tags: javascript, raphael

Raphael has a `Paper.set()`, which, if I understand correctly, is a group of elements. Is there a way to remove a set, like how elements have `Element.remove()`? I have tried writing a for loop on the set and calling remove on each element of it, but that does not appear to be how sets work.

Comment: I guess you will need to use jQuery to achieve this

Comment: Depends what you really want to do. You could either do a set.clear(), or set.forEach( function(el) { el.remove() } )  maybe ? Depending on what you really want to happen. It would help if you included the code when you say 'does not appear to be how sets work'